# Sonarqube code coverage metric with Jacoco

Tags: sonarqube, code-coverage, jacoco

I am using jacoco to get the code coverage metrics, and using sonar qube along with it for visualizing it.

Jacoco has multiple 'sub' coverages

- Line
- Method
- Branch
- Class
- Instruction

But if we look into sonarqube, it shows a single "Coverage" information.

Which of the above 5 coverages does sonarqube refers to?

Answer (score 1):

SonarQube is displaying Line Coverage. You can see details of it under Coverage Metrics. Example:

- Coverage 36.5%
- Lines to Cover 3,004
- Uncovered Lines 1,909
- Line Coverage 36.5%

You can also see Class/Project Coverage, when you change View from List to Tree or Treemap.

Comment: I think its a derived metric: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Metric+Definitions